# Chrome extension: get current page cookie and same to plugin local storage

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I tried the following but not sure how to manipulate it.

manifest.json

```
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["cookie.js"]
    }
  ]
```

cookie.js

```
console.log(document.cookie);
```

Is just shows in the currernt page console.log and not in the actual console of the extension.

Is it possible to grab the cookie of whatever current site you're on and set it in the localstorage of the extension? So at that point, I can be on any page and the extension will still have the value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following Skeleton helps in achieving it; I stored all `cookie` information in chrome extension Local Storage as shown here;

**Sample code**

[image]

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name" : "Cookie API Demo",
  "version" : "1",
  "description" : "This is demonstration of Cookie API",
  "permissions": [ "cookies","<all_urls>"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "screen.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

***popup.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***popup.js***

```
function cookieinfo(){
    chrome.cookies.getAll({},function (cookie){
        console.log(cookie.length);
        allCookieInfo = "";
        for(i=0;i<cookie.length;i++){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie[i]));

            allCookieInfo = allCookieInfo + JSON.stringify(cookie[i]);
        }
        localStorage.allCookieInfo = allCookieInfo;
    });
}
window.onload=cookieinfo;
```

For more API's check [THIS](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html)

**Skeleton For only Cookies in current Page**

As shown here you will have only cookie information in current page

[image]

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name" : "Cookie API Demo",
  "version" : "1",
  "description" : "This is demonstration of Cookie API",
  "permissions": [ "cookies","<all_urls>","tabs"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "screen.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

***popup.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***popup.js***

```
function cookieinfo(){

     chrome.tabs.query({"status":"complete","windowId":chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT,"active":true}, function(tab){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(tab));
            chrome.cookies.getAll({"url":tab[0].url},function (cookie){
                console.log(cookie.length);
                allCookieInfo = "";
                for(i=0;i<cookie.length;i++){
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie[i]));

                    allCookieInfo = allCookieInfo + JSON.stringify(cookie[i]);
                }
                localStorage.currentCookieInfo = allCookieInfo;
            });
    });

}
window.onload=cookieinfo;
```

Comment: This is perfect! my only problem is that it grab all the cookies i assume, how can it grab just one specific by its name for the current tab?

Comment: @delboud: I have updated the solution for that also, hope it helps

Comment: this works but its grabbing all of the cookies still, opposed to reading specificName=12345678 and getting 12345678

Comment: changed it to  `chrome.cookies.getAll({"url":tab[0].url,"name": 'nameOfCookieHere'},function (cookie){` and it works fine now!

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this goal in Firefox?